# Prove that the origin is an asymptotically stable critical point for a dynamical equation.

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

If p(0,0) and h(0) are positive, prove that the origin is an asymptotically stable critical point for the dynamical equation:

x'' + p(x,x')x' + xh(x) = 0.

I tried setting y = x' and y' = x'' and setting up a first order system of two equations to find the eigenvalues and determining the stability of the system based on that, but I ended up with a really ugly Jacobian and don't think I'm on the right path. I don't know how else I could possibly solve it.

Comment: Setting $p = p(0,0)$ and $h = h(0)$ we get the eigenvalues $-\frac p2\pm\sqrt{\frac{p^2}4-h}$. What can you say about the real parts of those two? For example, if $p^2/4>h$, then both eigenvalues are real and negative.

Comment: The real parts are always negative, hence the origin is always stable. Thanks, I think I understand the problem now.

Comment: Alright! :-)...